# Py2App - PyQt5 using wrong port_v#

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, py2app

I was building a simple GUI I made with PyQT5, and everything works fine during development build using py2app. When I go to to build the .app file, however I get a crash in the PyQt5 code:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/uic/port_v3/ascii_upper.py", line 24, in <module>
_ascii_trans_table = bytes.maketrans(b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

I've traced this down to what seems to be PyQt5 trying to run python 3 code from the port_v3 module, however I am doing everything in 2.7, and I can't figure out why it's trying to load Python 3 when it gets to building the PyQt portion of the app. Any ideas how to track this down or a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around and watching py2app take forever, seemingly trying to package every module installed on my machine for a simple app, I abandoned py2app altogether. I went with pyinstaller instead and it worked like a charm. Quick build and everything worked fine with all the dependencies for python 2.7.13 and PyQt5.

I know this isn't a solution to my original question about py2app, but still solved the original problem of trying to get an .app file bundled, so anyone else having this issue with py2app, I'd suggest trying pyinstaller.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.